# Python Recursion Alternatives for Training a Robot

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, reinforcement-learning

Actually, I am writing a code to train a robot in an unspecified grid. The Robot can move only UP/DOWN/LEFT/RIGHT. I start from point [0,0]. initially, my plan was to recursively figure out the coordinates but are there any other alternatives? I get recursion limit violation error as well.

How to write the non-recursive code of the following approach:

```
def play_episodes(current_point):
    global safe_block
    if(mine_safe_space(current_point) and visited_before(current_point)):
        check_state.add(conversion(current_point))
        safe_block += 1
        play_episodes([current_point[0] + 1, current_point[1]])
        play_episodes([current_point[0] - 1, current_point[1]])
        play_episodes([current_point[0], current_point[1] + 1])
        play_episodes([current_point[0], current_point[1] - 1])
```

Comment: You can use a queue to push/pop the states you need to process instead.

Comment: @Netwave Hey thank you for replying. If you don't min and if you have time can you give me an example? Thant would really help me to understand.

Comment: You can check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)

Comment: @Netwave Thank you so much. It worked. You are a savior!!